# Different style in code commenting

Tags: java, comments

What is the difference in commenting (in Eclipse at least) your code like this:

```
/**  
 * This is a comment  
 */
```

and this:

```
/*  
 * This is a comment  
 */
```

It appears in another colour.

Comment: Why did you include the spaces between the stars and the slashes if you didn't want them? Basically, `/* this is just a comment */`, but `/** this is a javadoc comment */`

Comment: @PeeHaa: No, after removing the spaces, both are comments.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: @PeeHaa: Which was mentioned in the question...

Comment: I didn't read it like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you for the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first syntax:

```
/**
 * This is a comment  
 */
```

Is a [JavaDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) comment, used for documentation, which is parsed automatically by IDEs and documentation tools.

```
/*
 * This is a comment  
 */
```

Is just a normal block-comment, used when you want to write a multi-line comment.

```
// This is a comment
```

Is just a normal, single-line comment.

See the [JavaDoc Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html) here.

Answer (score 1):

the second one is a comment while the first one would be helpful if javaDoc is ever generated for you program set .

the first comment would appear as a JAVADoc description of the method following it .

for your case [ 2 nd one ] it seems that you have a method following the comment that has a paramter **this**  which has the description of  **is a comment**